# Spring:RestTemplate: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, json, spring, httpresponse

I know multiple posts regarding similar issue present on StackOverflow already and I have also gone through some posts and tried to solve my problem but facing others issue. I'll walk through my implementations and explain challenges faced. Please guide me.

**Request Header**: `'Content-Type: application/json','Accept: "text/html,application/xml;q=0.9,application/xhtml+xml,text/xml;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5,application/json;charset=UTF-8"`

**API call**: `ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, httpEntity, String.class, paramMap);`

**Responding API**: `Content-Type: application/json`

1. Initially I was getting below exception and gone through multiple posts on SO and implemented this solution:
   **Exception**: `org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String] and content type [application/json]`
   **Implementation done**:

```html
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(); 
jackson2Converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL)); 
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters = restTemplate.getMessageConverters();
httpMessageConverters.add(jackson2Converter);

restTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters);
```

After this change, I started getting, below exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901) at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:730) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:795) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:617) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588) at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:507) at
```

To solve the above problem, I did below changes:

```html
requestHeaders.set("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE); 

RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate(); 
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverters = getHttpMessageConverters(); 
restTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverters); 
 
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, httpEntity, String.class, paramMap); 
 
 
private List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getHttpMessageConverters() { 
  StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(); 
  stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL)); 
  MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2Converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(); 
  jackson2Converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL)); 
  return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jackson2Converter, stringConverter));
}
```

After the above changes I started getting below exception:

```
Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@99ef5fc; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@99ef5fc; line: 1, column: 1]","context":"default","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@99ef5fc; line: 1, column: 1]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@99ef5fc; line: 1, column: 1]\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:227)\n\tat org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:212)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:95)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:884)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:868)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:622)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:588)\n\tat org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:507)\n\tat
```

Please let me know, where I am doing wrong and what is the gap in my understanding and implementation. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Spring RestTemplate will configure itself with a series of HttpMessageConverters based on what is available in the classpath.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java

Since you don't appear to be using a custom Jackson ObjectMapper in your MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, you don't actually need to configure one. In fact, the only thing you're doing for your message converter is invoking the following:

```
jackson2Converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL));
```

Which, as I understand it, is used to indicate that this message converter is capable of converting all media types (which is not true).

I suspect that all you really need is this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = getRestTemplate(); 
 
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, httpEntity, String.class, paramMap);
```

However, even then it might not work since you're providing the following accept criteria in your request:

```
Accept: "text/html,application/xml;q=0.9,application/xhtml+xml,text/xml;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5,application/json;charset=UTF-8"
```

I would try excluding the accept header first, and if that doesn't work I would try setting it to application/json.

Comment: I was using below code only in my project:

Comment: please ignore above comment:

@dew_the_fifth: As you explained in "I suspect that all you really need is this:", I had implemented that code only but this is the initial problem when I started getting : **Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.lang.String] and content type [application/json]**.

Comment: I would actually expect the ```org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter``` to be the message converter used to handle application/json being parsed as a String.

In your sample code, where you're calling setMessageConverters, you're effectively stripping that converter out of your available set. However if you were using what I sent, only creating the RestTemplate and using it by default, it should have the StringHttpMessageConverter to use.

Can you check that there is an instance of the StringHttpMessageConverter configured on the RestTemplate you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your input, as suggested by you just changing the Accept header to 'application/json' solved the issue without modifying RestTemplate HttpMessageConverter. Will monitor for some time and check if things seems fine.